# Python / Beautifulsoup: HTML Path to the current element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For a class project, I'm working on extracting all links on a webpage.  This is what I have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

with open("input.htm") as inputFile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(inputFile)

outputFile=open('output.txt', 'w')
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
outputFile.write(str(link)+'\n')
outputFile.close()
```

This works very well.

Here's the complication: for every `<a>` element, my project requires me to know the entire "tree structure" to the current link.  In other words, I'd like to know all the precendent elements starting with the the `<body>` element.  And the `class` and `id` along the way.

Like the navigation page on Windows explorer.  Or the navigation panel on many browsers' element inspection tool.

For example, if you look at the Bible page on Wikipedia and a link to the Wikipedia page for the Talmud, the following "path" is what I'm looking for.

```
<body class="mediawiki ...>
 <div id="content" class="mw-body" role="main">
  <div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content">
   <div id="mw-content-text" ...>
    <div class="mw-parser-output">
     <div role="navigation" ...>
      <table class="nowraplinks ...>
       <tbody>
        <td class="navbox-list ...>
         <div style="padding:0em 0.25em">
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="/wiki/Talmud"
```

Thanks a bunch.
-Maureen

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(inputFile, 'html.parser')
```

Or use lxml:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(inputFile, 'lxml')
```

If it is not installed:

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: hello dear Alex - many thanks for adding the idea to do this with lxml - ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I just wrote. It works by finding the element, then navigating up the tree by the elements parent. I parse just the opening tag and add it to a list. Reverse the list at the end. Finally we end up with a list that resembles the tree you requested.

I have written it for one element, you can modify it to work with your find_all

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tree = []

hrefElement = soup.find('a', href=True)
hrefString = str(hrefElement).split(">")[0] + ">"
tree.append(hrefString)

hrefParent = hrefElement.find_parent()
while (hrefParent.name != "html"):
    hrefString = str(hrefParent).split(">")[0] + ">"
    tree.append(hrefString)
    hrefParent = hrefParent.find_parent()

tree.reverse()
print(tree)
```

Comment: hello dear Sri - many thanks that you provide a solution  - looks pretty interesting. i get back ` 
'<body class="mediawiki ltr sitedir-ltr mw-hide-empty-elt ns-0 ns-subject page-Bible rootpage-Bible skin-vector action-view">', '<div class="mw-body" id="content" role="main">', '<div class="mw-indicators mw-body-content">', '<div class="mw-indicator" id="mw-indicator-pp-default">', '<a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy#semi" title="This article is semi-protected.">']`
[Finished in 4.645s]

Comment: Yes the output should be something like that. Is there anything I did wrong?